# Unable to use Chrome WebDriver with a Chromium based browser

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I need to use WebDriver for automated testing in a custom Chromuim-based browser, but after starting tests it just opens a blank page in that browser with "data:," in the address bar.

I know that the issue usually occurs when the Chromium and ChromeDriver versions don't match, but I downloaded ChromeDriver of the same version as the browser's Chromium has.

The code I try to execute for now is pretty simple:

```java
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\tools\\chromedriver-84.0.4147.30\\chromedriver.exe");
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions().setBinary("C:\\Program Files (x86)\\SputnikLab\\Sputnik\\Application\\browser.exe");
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
driver.get("https://www.google.com");
```

Which obviously works if I change the binary path to the actual Chrome, but that's not what I need. Also I tried to use older and the latest versions of ChromeDriver, which didn't work either (led to the same result).

The output is empty while the code is executing, but after closing the "data:," window, the stack trace is like this:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Could not start a new session. Response code 500. Message: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited normally.
  (chrome not reachable)
  (The process started from chrome location C:\Program Files (x86)\SputnikLab\Sputnik\Application\browser.exe is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.) 
Build info: version: '4.10.0', revision: 'c14d967899'
System info: os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '20.0.1'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
Command: [null, newSession {capabilities=[Capabilities {browserName: chrome, goog:chromeOptions: {args: [--remote-allow-origins=*], binary: C:\Program Files (x86)\Sput..., extensions: []}}]}]
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:140)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:96)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:68)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:163)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.invokeExecute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:196)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:171)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:531)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:227)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:154)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chromium.ChromiumDriver.<init>(ChromiumDriver.java:107)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:87)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:82)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:71)
    at Main.main(Main.java:13)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

If the browser download link is needed, I can provide it in the comments.

Comment: Update the question with your code trials and the error stacktrace.